# nginx and php5-fpm not working

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

Before anything, I searched everywhere and tested everything,
but still not working.
I install `php5-fpm` and `nginx`. When I open `localhost`  in browser I see this page :

```
Welcome to nginx!
```

So it's working now configuring php5-fpm with nginx `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`:

```
  user = www-data
  group = www-data
  listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
  listen.owner = www-data
  listen.group = www-data
  pm = dynamic
  pm.max_children = 5
  pm.start_servers = 2
  pm.min_spare_servers = 1
  pm.max_spare_servers = 3
  chdir = /
```

All other lines are commented and this is the nginx conf :

```
  upstream php {
        server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.socket;
  }

server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html index.htm index.php;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name localhost;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}

# Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
#location /RequestDenied {
#   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
#}

#error_page 404 /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
#error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#location = /50x.html {
#   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;

}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#   allow all;
#}
}
```

The problem is when I try to run `.php` files `nginx` will download `.php` file instead of executing it.

Comment: So it's working, eh? And what's your problem?

Comment: my problem is that this config should work but instead of executing the php file nginx will download it

Comment: Please avoid cross-posting http://stackoverflow.com/q/25133429/2010467

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## PHP-FPM socket permissions

Please check that the socket has proper permissions.

```
$ ll /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
srw-rw---- 1 www-data www-data 0 Aug  6 14:16 /var/run/php5-fpm.sock=
```

Probably add `listen.mode = 0660` to your `www.conf` if the output is different.

Possibly related: [nginx error connect to php5-fpm.sock failed (13: Permission denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23443398/2010467)

## nginx configuration

1. Is this really where your files are?

   ```
   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   index index.html index.htm index.php;
   ```
2. What is this block supposed to do?

   ```
     upstream php {
           server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.socket;
     }
   ```
3. I'd suggest removing `try_files $uri =404;` from the `location ~ \.php$` block.
4. Why is the indentation of the lines in 2 and 3 different from the rest? Note  that it would affect a proper configuration, but this leaves the impression that they have been carelessly pasted together. Please provide a link to the instructions you used.

Comment: I removed try files on location / and that worked. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [EasyEngine](https://github.com/rtCamp/easyengine) which can setup webserver with single command

Docs/wiki: https://github.com/rtCamp/easyengine/wiki

How to setup: http://www.unixmen.com/easyengine-auto-installer-script-managing-wordpress-nginx-websites-ubuntu-debian/